# prolog member predicate: understanding behavior

Tags: list, prolog

SWI-Prolog provides a built-in function for inferring membership of an element to a list.

```
?- member(blah,[blah,bleh,blach]).                               
true .
```

According to [this source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Lists), member is defined as follows:

```
member(X, [X|_]).        % member(X, [Head|Tail]) is true if X = Head 
                         % that is, if X is the head of the list
member(X, [_|Tail]) :-   % or if X is a member of Tail,
  member(X, Tail).       % ie. if member(X, Tail) is true.
```

In trying to better understand how member works, I observed the following when querying for all lists of which some element is a member:

```
?- member(x,List).                           
List = [x|_G268] ;                                               
List = [_G267, x|_G271] ;                                        
List = [_G267, _G270, x|_G274] ;                                 
List = [_G267, _G270, _G273, x|_G277] ;                          
List = [_G267, _G270, _G273, _G276, x|_G280] ;
List = [_G267, _G270, _G273, _G276, _G279, x|_G283] ;
List = [_G267, _G270, _G273, _G276, _G279, _G282, x|_G286]
```

Does anyone have an explanation of what these _G2xx values meaning and origin?

Comment: Are you asking "why are they called like that" as in "why the letter *G*, and why this number" ? Or are you asking why your *member* call is never ending ?

Comment: A variable beginning with `_` is a variable that you aren't concerned about the value of. It may be referred to as a [*named singleton variable*](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/syntax.html#sec:2.15.2.6) since the naming convention is typically used to name a variable that you don't intend to use anywhere else (it only occurs in this one instance). So, for example, `[x|_G268]` means a list whose first element is `x` and the tail is just *whatever* (don't care).

Comment: @ZakariaChihani it's clear why my recursion is never ending-- there are an infinite set of lists each of a different length of which x can be a member. I'm asking why the underscore variable is named as it is and if it represents anything more than just an unusually named variable.

Comment: It seems like the underscore variable naming scheme is designed to generate unique placeholders that don't collide. The letters and numbers that follow the underscore have little significance beyond avoiding collision. Am I correct?

Comment: @DavidShaked absolutely. And It is maintained and managed by the compiler. So you need not concern yourself about it ;)

Comment: Try a query like this: `?- member(x, List), numbervars(List, 0, _).` This will give your variables nicer names. You can look up what `numbervars/3` does.

Comment: @ZakariaChihani, yes, the interpreter will generate unique names with `_` prefix. They have to be unique. Two variables of the same name, even starting with `_`, are considered to be unified, which would make the results false.